# Is ORDER BY  honoured in SQL Server views?

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-order-by

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087673/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-sqlserver-views/4088508#4088508) to [What are the downsides of using SqlServer Views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087673/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-sqlserver-views), hyprsleepy suggests the `ORDER BY` clause is not honoured in views in SQL Server.

Could anyone explain why this is the case?

Edit:  Thanks for the answers, but I'm not sure thats the issue.  I know you cant add an Order By Clause to a view and I dont have a problem with that, you just add it to the `SELECT` statement when calling the view, but my impression from the other question was that using an Order By Clause in a `SELECT` statement on a view will not give the correct results every time.

Comment: +1 For the question. BTW, it makes perfect sense to me for a View not to be ordered

Comment: I agree, which is why I was confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SQL Server` developers assume that any set operation may change the order of the records so there is no point to use `ORDER BY` in the intermediate set definitions and it only makes sense in the final statements.

The views may be used in joins or other operations which invalidates their orders.

Since you cannot use the view by itself, i. e. you don't write `vMyView`, you rather write `SELECT * FROM vMyView`, despite the fact that the view is a `SELECT` per se, you can (and should) append the `ORDER BY` clause to the `SELECT` statement as well if you need an order.

This is quite a sane assumption and in fact it makes the code more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Create a sorted view in SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/create-a-sorted-view-in-sql-server-2005--2008)

There is a way to do it but it is not supported, just issue an order by when selecting from the view

Comment: is an ORDER BY Clause in your `SELECT` statement always executed correctly?

Comment: Yes it is, so just do `select <SomeColumns> from view order by <SomeColumns>`

Comment: Ok - so there is no problem as far as I'm concerned, I appear to have misunderstood the answer to the other question.

Answer (score 2):

In your view definition include TOP 100 PERCENT as a workaround. You can then use ORDER BY.

EDIT or as SQLMenace pointed out TOP 99.99 PERCENT.

Comment: Doesn't do anything in 2005 and up, see here: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/create-a-sorted-view-in-sql-server-2005--2008

Comment: And here is why: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/24/560396.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28database%29):

> Just as rows in a base table lack any
>   defined ordering, rows available
>   through a view do not appear with any
>   default sorting. A view is a
>   relational table, and the relational
>   model defines a table as a set of
>   rows. Since sets are not ordered - by
>   definition - the rows in a view are
>   not ordered, either. Therefore, an
>   ORDER BY clause in the view definition
>   is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put an ORDER BY clause in your views. The exact error is:

*"The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified."*

Comment: You can create it...however it doesn't do anything in 2005 and up, see: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/create-a-sorted-view-in-sql-server-2005--2008